# Lambda VPC configuration setting for redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda

I want to understand, why there is a  need to configure vpc to access only redis and not other services( like dynamo db ) from lambda function

Comment: because your redis only allows access from inside the VPC.  Other services like s3 are on public endpoints and allow public access

Answer (score 0):

Redis (either on an EC2 instance, or via ElastiCache) runs inside your VPC. So does EC2 and RDS and Redshift and several other AWS services. If you want to access one of those services that run inside your VPC then you would have to configure your Lambda function to have VPC access.

Other services, like DynamoDB, that don't exist inside the VPC obviously don't require VPC access.

As for the reason why some services are inside the VPC and not others, the services that exist in the VPC tend to be things where you specify a specific server configuration (server size, number of servers, etc) and you run those servers inside your virtual network (VPC). On the other hand there are some services like DynamoDB where the actual back-end server size and quantity are not exposed to you. Amazon completely manages these servers and you don't even get to know how many of them there are. These servers do not exist inside your virtual network, and you only access these services via the AWS API.